# $geoNear requires a 2d or 2dsphere index, but none were found found this problem getData api in node.js +monodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, aggregation-framework

When i call getData() api its show error : `"$geoNear requires a 2d or 2dsphere index, but none were found"`

someone say that put this line : `db.collection.createIndex( { <location field> : "2dsphere" } )`
but i dont know where i want to put this line So please help im new in node

below I put my schema & getData api
**PostSchema.js**

```
var schema = new Schema({
  userId: {
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'users'
  },
  price: {
    type: Number
  },
  details: {
    type: String
  },
  location: {
    type: {
      type: String,
      default: "Point"
    },
    coordinates: [Number]
  }
}, {
  collection: 'posts',
  toObject: {
    virtuals: true
  },
  toJSON: {
    virtuals: true
  },
  versionKey: false
})

schema.indexes({ location: '2dsphere' })
```

**getDataAPI**

```
 getAllPosts: async (req, res) => {
        try {
         
            let filterQuery = {
                userId: { $ne: req.user._id },
            }

            let aggregateQuery = [];
            aggregateQuery.push({
                $geoNear: {
                    near: { type: "Point", coordinates: req.user.location.coordinates },
                    distanceField: "distanceFrom",
                    spherical: true,
                    query: filterQuery,
                    distanceMultiplier: 0.001
                }
            })


            let posts = await Post.aggregate(aggregateQuery);
      

            return res.status(200).json({
                success: true,
                message: 'Posts get successfully',
                data: posts
            })
        } catch (err) {
            return res.status(400).json({
                success: false,
                message: err && err.message ? err.message : 'Something went wrong',
                data: {}
            })
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try to replace the `indexes` with `index` in your schema definition

```
var schema = new Schema({
  ...
  location: {
    type: {
      type: String,
      default: "Point"
    },
    coordinates: [Number]
  }
  ...
)

schema.index({ location: '2dsphere' })
```

Check out the officially on creating [Indexes](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html#indexes)

Comment: Thank you dear Its working now, but just get one warning which is `DeprecationWarning: collection.ensureIndex is deprecated. Use createIndexes instead`

Comment: By using this line that warning also gone  `DB. mongoose.connect("YOUR DB URL", { useNewUrlParser: true, useCreateIndex: true });`